# cant map var to sec y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

im trying to plot two varibales on the same plot with 2 diffrent y axis.

i'v done this before using sec_axis, but now, the two vavaribales are maping to the primery axis only...

what could be the reason ?

Thanks

code:

```
pp2 <- ggplot(TM068means,aes(x= Tm1,y= + Mean.O.D.X1000)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width = 0.3,position = "dodge",fill="Blue")+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y =n), color = "red")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 450), breaks = seq(0,450, by = 50),sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Number of plants")) +
  labs(title="TM-068",subtitle = expression(atop(italic("Tm 1"))), x = "Genotype",y = "Average O.D X 1000")+
  theme(text = element_text(family="Palatino Linotype"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.title =element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 40),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 30),
        axis.title.x= element_text(face = "bold", size = 30,margin = margin(t = 10, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.y=element_text(color = "Blue",face = "bold",size = 30,margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 30,color = "Black",face = "bold",angle=45,hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 30,color = "Blue",face = "bold"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'Black', size=1, linetype='solid'),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'Blue', size=1, linetype='solid'),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "Blue"),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red",size=1, linetype='solid'), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red",size = 30,face = "bold"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red",margin = margin(t = 0, l = 15, b = 0, r = 0)),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

I tried to map to different vars for 2 different y axis

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg